# Excluding values in pandas data frame if already occurred in a specific pattern

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I am using python 3.4, with pandas, in pycharm

I have arranged my data in a pandas data frame that looks more or less like this:
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'step': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        'trials': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]}
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

the problem is that 'step' at row[15] and step at row[16] are respectively 8 and 1 and such difference is not tolerable for the type of analysis I am running. So I would like to exclude / remove / drop ALL the rows in between row 15 and the row at which the value 'step' goes back to row[15], which in this case is 8 and it can be found at row[23]. [EDITED after first answer received] Keep in mind that the rule is that any subsequent value can only be +/- 1. So, for example, 'step' at row[9] is 4, which is smaller than 'step' at row[8] which is 5. Such difference is allowed, any difference bigger than +- 1 is not.

This is just an example, the real data has hundreds of thousands of rows, so I expect to have this problem more than once in my data frame.

I have been looking at ways to iterate through the rows with for loops and such, but I have been warned about those methods being very slow. And in any case I could not come up with a working for loop.

I also failed at finding a smart programatic way of doing this without loops and simply using pandas and some sort of logical indexing. I am not even sure if this is possibile without iterating. For now I can successfully find all the rows at which de difference of row[i] and row[i+1] is bigger than modulus[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faAQk.png) and logically index that, but I am stuck at this point.

Eventually I would a data frame where rows from 16 to 22 are excluded.

Answer (score 0):

If someone would post a shorter solution' I'll delete it, but what I've found is to create a `df` who finds the first `trials` for each step, and if there was already a higher `step` in a previous `trials` then delete it:

```
first_apps = temp_df.sort_values(['step', 'trials']).drop_duplicates('step')
first_apps['next_step'] = first_apps['trials'].shift(-1)
temp_df = temp_df.merge(first_apps.drop('trials', axis=1), how='left')
temp_df = temp_df[~(temp_df['trials'] > temp_df['next_step'])].drop('next_step', axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution, unfortunately I did not explain my problem very well. See, a difference of +/- 1 between trial n an trial+1 should be allowed. Is a difference bigger than +/-1 that should be not allowed. I will make this more clear in the original question.

Comment: @antcolony So line 22 is OK, and should not be excluded (its `step` is 7 and line 15's `step` was 8)?

Comment: well, in this special case line 22 is not ok. But if this specific rule makes it harder to code, I can drop it

Answer (score 0):

My own solution, after some more researching, is a combination of loop and dataframe manipulation.

I first create two additional columns: one with the shift in 'step' between every row and the next row column step shifted by one row `temp_df['shift'] = temp_df.shift(-1)`; and one, called jump, with a simple logical index that is set to True if any value in the new column is bigger than 1 `temp_df['jump'] = temp_df['diff'] > 1`

Then I basically create an index of all the "jumps" and run a for loop where:
1) I extract the index and the value of the first jump in the series ('curr_idx' and 'curr_value')
2) I copy a subset of the original data frame, from the index to the end, into a new data frame ('temp_df2'
3) I look for the index of the first occurrence of the value of the first jump, in the new data frame ('last_value')
4) I drop the rows in the original data frame from the first index to the last index ('curr_idx : last_value')

I also do everything under 'Try:' because this solution throws an error i could not manage to resolve. Sorry for that.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'step': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

temp_df['diff'] = temp_df['step'] - temp_df['step'].shift(-1)
temp_df['jump'] = temp_df['diff'] > 1
temp_df = temp_df.reset_index(drop=True)

old_df = temp_df

all_values = temp_df[temp_df['jump']]['step']

try:
    for i in range(0,len(all_values)):

        # find all positions at which jump is true
        all_values = temp_df[temp_df['jump']]['step']
        curr_idx = temp_df[temp_df['jump']].index.values.astype(int)[0]
        curr_value = all_values.iloc[0]

        temp_df2 = temp_df.drop(temp_df.index[0:curr_idx+1])
        last_value = temp_df2[temp_df2['step'] == curr_value].index.values.astype(int)[0]

        temp_df = temp_df.drop(temp_df.index[curr_idx:last_value])
        temp_df = temp_df.reset_index(drop=True)
except:
    pass

plt.subplot(121)
ax1 = plt.plot(old_df['step'])

plt.subplot(122)
ax2 = plt.plot(temp_df['step'])
```

and here the output:
[image]